# Should all application settings be injected from the Spring configuration?

Tags: spring, configuration

I have a small Spring based application and one of my classes needs additional configuration data. Normally I'd solve this via `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and passing through the settings.

In my situation the targeted class is not configured in `spring.xml` and it would perhaps require some refactoring to pass the setting along the target class' parent classes, so I was wandering if it is ok to make the target class (or some related class) read an external properties file.

Is this a good approach or does it violate the principles of Spring? Or in other words: Should all external configuration be injected from the application configuration (`spring.xml`) or is it ok to read it later during the applications lifecycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legacy code is the reality of many Spring applications, so you have to be realistic about these things.  Sometimes, as you say, it's not practical to inject *everything*, even if you'd like to.

Since one of the main advantages of IoC is ease of testing, my advice would be for your class to fetch its configuration using a mechanism that can also be easily tested. In other words - don't use statics to fetch your config.

So I wouldn't get too hung up on things not being "springy", as long as you can still get some of the advantages that IoC brings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this is handled in general. I am currently working on a project, where we implement Spring to configure different components and have them instantiated by Spring. Before we started using Spring, we needed to insure the order in which all components would be created by the main programm. Aside from that, we still use `app.config` to specify other information such as timeout duration, connection strings for a database and such. One static component is used to read the configuration on program start and the other components can reference that instance for the information they need.

Hope this answers your question.